# Define and plot function from ThermoDynamicData

Tags: plotting, curated-data

I have a hunch that this is a straightforward variant of similar questions regarding how functions are evaluated by Plot, but this case has me stumped. Let's say I want to produce a plot of the density of water as a function of temperature. So I define

```
DensWater[temp_] := 
 ThermodynamicData["Water", "Density", 
     {"Temperature" -> Quantity[temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}]
```

I can call this function with any value for T such as `DensWater[25.0]` and I receive a result with an attached unit as expected. However, when I try to plot this function using

```
Plot[DensWater[T], {T, 10., 65.}]
```

I get `ThermodynamicData::quant: T is not a real number.`

I did try various ways to get this resolved, but somehow can't get the `Plot` command to work without giving error messages. What's the trick?

P.S.: Just to be clear, the `Plot` command does provide a plot in the end, I'm just surprised by the error message.

**Update:**

The above is just a minor annoyance, but if I define a function of two variables, say pressure and temperature like so:

```
DensAir[T_, p_] := 
 ThermodynamicData["Air", "Density", 
    {"Temperature" -> Quantity[T, "DegreesCelsius"], "Pressure" -> Quantity[p, "Pascals"]}]
```

and try to plot this using `Plot3D`, I get an empty plot. When plotting 2D slices of the above function using `Plot`this function works as above (with error messages, but giving a plot).

Comment: Worked in M10.4 Linux - no error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you get the "XXX is not a real number" type of error message, a method to get around the error is to put a constraint on the pattern when you define the function to ensure that only real numbers will be evaluated:

```
DensWater[temp_?NumericQ] := 
  ThermodynamicData["Water", 
   "Density", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}];
```

You can see how this works via

```
DensWater[t]
DensWater[20.0]
(* DensWater[t] *)
(* Quantity[998.207, ("Kilograms")/("Meters")^3] *)
```

The first call does not get evaluated, because there's no pattern definition that matches.  This fixes the error you get when you call `Plot`.  One suggestion I have is that it's faster to make one call to the paclet for a list of temperatures than to repeatedly call the paclet for different temperatures.  This gives your plot a bit faster (assuming you've quit the kernel, because `ThermodynamicData` caches the results),

```
DensWater[temp_?NumericQ | temp_List] := 
 ThermodynamicData["Water", 
  "Density", {"Temperature" -> Quantity[temp, "DegreesCelsius"]}]
ListLinePlot[DensWater[Range[10, 60]]]
```

Now about the second issue, I can't seem to get `Plot3D` to work with data that has units.  Using the same method as above, with `DensAir[T_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ]:= ......`, I get no error message but I still get no plot unless I strip the `Quantity` head,

[image]

This seems like a bug to me.  Also, when I try to use the trick above for giving lists directly to `ThermodynamicData` in two dimensions I get "ThermodynamicData::time: Calculation exceeded time limit" errors.